# PHP if requested URL like

Tags: php, string, string-search

I would like to know how to do an 'if requested URL like' statement. For example, I currently have the following code, but I want to the base, icon and logo applied on all locations after route=checkout/

What is the wildcard value? Am I on the right lines?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="/index.php?route=checkout/checkout")
$base='https://domain.co.uk/>';
$icon='/image/data/favicon.png';
$logo='/image/data/logo.png';
?>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you reword it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is perhaps what you want?

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/index.php?route=checkout') !== false) {
// Do your stuff here.
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks!

What if I want multiple values such as

    '/index.php?route=checkout'
    '/index.php?route=account'
    '/index.php?route=affiliate'

How could I do that?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to do the matching (preg_match(/(checkout|affiliate|account)/, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) (note: I didn't test that), or you could parse out the uri bits using parse_url: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and then check the query parameters on their own.